# AWS Cloudformation Template with letsencrypt SSL certificate

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I want to create a AWS Cloudformation Template with

- single EC2 instance which has a apache webserver and a letsencrypt SSL certificate
- a Route53 A record which is a dynamic template parameter

I can get letsencrypt to run, because I need to complete a challenge https://letsencrypt.org/de/docs/challenge-types/.

**The problem:** The HTTP-01 challenge needs the Route53 A record to be created before the EC2 instance, but this is not possible because I need the IP address of the EC2 instance to create the Route53 A record.

I thought about using an EIP but the EIP can only be associated after the EC2 instance is created not on the same time, so the challenge fails too.

The dns-01 challenge is not possible in cloudformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will install a certbot SSL certificate on a Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance with an apache webserver**

The Problem is, that for the ssl verfifcation challenge, you would need a domain pointing to that EC2 instance, but the domain can olny be set after the EC2 instance creation with cloudformation.

I found a solution which waits until the domain is set with CloudFormation

```
    Resources:
      WebServerInstance:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
        Metadata:
          AWS::CloudFormation::Init:


            InstallApache:
              packages:
                yum:
                  httpd: []

           InstallCerbotSsl:
              packages:
                yum:
                  certbot: []
                  python2-certbot-apache: []
              files:
                /use/bin/install_certbot_after_domain_is_set_route53.sh:
                  content: !Sub |
                      #!/bin/bash

                      while true; do
                        certbot -i apache -a apache --preferred-challenges http -d "${Domain}" -m ${AdminEmail} -n --redirect --agree-tos

                        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
                        then
                          echo "Certbot success"

                          service httpd restart
                          break
                        else
                          echo "retry..."
                          sleep 10
                        fi
                      done
                  mode: '000600'
                  owner: root
                  group: root
            InstallCrontab:
              files:
                /var/spool/cron/root:
                  content: !Sub |
                    # m h dom mon dow      command
                    39 1,13 * * * certbot renew --no-self-upgrade > /dev/null 2>&1

                  mode: '000600'
                  owner: root
                  group: root
```

this will a a domain to the stack, which the certbot needs to verify the httpd challenge:

```
DNSRecord:
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
  Properties:
    HostedZoneName: foo.de.
    Name: !Ref Domain
    Type: A
    TTL: 300
    ResourceRecords:
      - !GetAtt WebServerInstance.PublicIp
```

and a UserData trigger, which is executed after the creation success signal fpr the CF Stack to step on in the creation process

```
 UserData:
    # is executed as root user
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash

        # create EC2 instance
        yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap

        # create EC2 instance
        /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource WebServerInstance --configsets InstallAndRun --region ${AWS::Region}

        # send create success signal to cloudformation
        /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource WebServerInstance --region ${AWS::Region}

        # update all packages to latest
        yum update -y

        service httpd restart

        # install certbot sll certificate, can take some time until domain is set
        bash /use/bin/install_certbot_after_domain_is_set_route53.sh > /use/bin/install_certbot.log

        # reboot system
        reboot
```